# Move SSAS database to another server without detach-attach

Tags: restore, ssas

We take drive level snapshots of our source server every day, so we have copies of the folder `OLAP\DATA`.

We are trying to restore a database from 10th March and 11th March to a destination server with names like `xyz_10march` & `xyz_11march`.

Is that even possible?

Unfortunately, our company takes drive level snapshots every day for all servers irrespective of being SQL Server or SSAS. If I have to attach a SQL Server database, it's easy - but how do I attach it for an SSAS database?